# Decay of a decreasing summable sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of non-negative real numbers, such that $\sum_n x_n\leq C<\infty$ for some $C>0$.

What is the optimal upper bound I can have about $x_n$'s decay?

I think I remember something like $x_n=o(1/n)$ but I am not sure, and I would more like something quantitative like $x_n\leq C/n$. Do you have any idea?

EDIT: I wrote $o(n)$ instead of $o(1/n)$ in the first place, i apologize for this. Many answers state that $o(1)$ is the best bound, but I'm quite sure that the fact that $a_n$ is non-increasing yields $a_n=o(1/n)$.

Comment: Indeed the sequence is decreasing, so the best bound i can get is $o(1/n)$?

Comment: What do you mean "nondecreasing"? If the sequence is non-decreasing (and non-zero) the sum is infinite.

Comment: ıt may be helpful that  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}nx_{2n}=0$ for your series.

Comment: I don't understand how a non-trivial non-decreasing sequence can be in $o(1/n)$...

Comment: If I assume that $nx_{2n}$ goes to $0$ i (almost) have $x_n=o(1/n)$...

Answer (score 2):

The question seems now to be the following:

> Let $(x_n)$ denote a positive and decreasing sequence such that the series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges, show that $x_n=o(1/n)$.

A proof goes as follows: the series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges hence $\sum\limits_{k\gt n}x_k\to0$ when $n\to\infty$.
In particular, $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k\to0$. The sequence $(x_k)$ is decreasing hence $x_k\geqslant x_{2n}$ for every $n+1\leqslant k\leqslant2n$ and $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k\geqslant nx_{2n}$, which proves that $2nx_{2n}\to0$. 
Likewise (but other arguments are possible), $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n+1}x_k\to0$ hence $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n}x_k\geqslant (n+1)x_{2n+1}\geqslant (n+\frac12)x_{2n+1}$, which proves that $(2n+1)x_{2n+1}\to0$. Finally, $nx_n\to0$, that is, $x_n=o(1/n)$.

**Edit:** The same elementary approach yields $x_n\leqslant C/n$ for every $n\geqslant1$, with $C=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x_k$.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the first part of your answer, but for the converse you can actually have $o(1/n)$.

Comment: I dont understand that how we can conclude $nx_n\to0$ from $$2nx_{2n}\to0\quad and\quad (2n+1)x_{2n+1}\to0 $$

Comment: thanks for your answer but i know that, my question is about a better bound, such as $o(1/(n\log(n)))$

Comment: Compare "i know that" and "I think I remember something like xn=o(1/n) but I am not sure". The things you know and those you do not, seem to change awfully quickly.

Comment: By the way, the quantitative in "I would more like something quantitative like xn≤C/n" is actually obvious--but maybe you also know how to prove it now?

Comment: If you read what I said (and apparently you did), I'm not interested in proving $x_n=o(1/n)$, sorry for your rep. points. I am interested in either a better bound, or an explicit constant $C$ in $x_n\leq C/n$.

Comment: Rep points mean nothing, only weak souls care about them. Imprecise questions with shifting subject on the other hand...

Answer (score 0):

User @Did's answer is the real deal, but I'm posting this argument year because it is really elementary.

---

Because the sequence is nonnegative decreasing the $n$ term is less than or equal to the average of the first $n$ terms, i.e $x_n \le S_n/n$, where $S_n$ is the $n$th partial sum. But $S_n \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k \le C \lt \infty$ since $(x_k)_k \in \ell_1$ by assumption. We deduce that

$$
x_n \le C/n\text{ for all } n\ge 1.
$$